# Enlarge Selected Item/Image In A Listbox

Tags: wpf

I have a listbox with images inside it. I want a horizontal row of images with no gap between them, with the selected item being larger than the rest.
I've tried playing with transforms to makes all the other images smaller but this seemed to keep the item container the same size so I ended up with large gaps inbetween the images.
My source code without any transforms or triggers is below.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListBox.Template>            
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding Poster}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you applied the transform as [`RenderTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) which does not affect layout, apply it as [`LayoutTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) instead and it should work.

---

e.g.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Poster}">
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
        </Image>
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <CubicEase x:Key="ease" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                EasingFunction="{StaticResource ease}"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                To="1.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                EasingFunction="{StaticResource ease}"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                To="1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Many Thanks HB - Layout transform did the trick. I actually read your answer before you posted the code so I'll try the storyboards now. I'm sure it'll look much better that what I have ;-) The only issue I have is a slight gap between the images, presumably for the border when I select the item.  Do you know where I can edit this?

Comment: @Oli: I think that could be in ther control template of the `ListBoxItems`. **Edit:** I just just confirmed it, override the `Template` and it is gone (unless you add it in your own template as well of course)

Comment: @HB I've got rid of the "Dotted" border by settings FocusVisualStyle to null but the background is still changing to blue (I thought it was a border as most of the background is hidden by the image) I'm overriding the style in <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> - Is that the right place?

Comment: @Oli: Yes, but you need a setter to change the `Template`.